# Cannot display Object in ThreeJS. Getting error: THREE.OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "usemap glass"

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

Got this error while running threejs in an angular 8 application. Im just trying to load an object. The object and material files were downloaded from [Kenney assets](https://www.kenney.nl/assets/space-kit). I've looked at the oficial threejs site examples, just as [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj_mtl), and some other examples online. The code is:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import {MTLLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader";
import {OBJLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader";
```

```js
    new MTLLoader()
      .load('./../../../../../assets/Models/buildingCorridorOpen.mtl', function (materials) {
      materials.preload();
      new OBJLoader()
        .load('./../../../../../assets/Models/buildingCorridorOpen.obj', function (mesh) {
        mesh.position.set(0, 0.5, 0);
        scene.add(mesh);
      });
    });
```

And the full error is the following:

```js
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: THREE.OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "usemap _defaultMat"
    at OBJLoader.parse (OBJLoader.js:633)
    at Object.onLoad (OBJLoader.js:402)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.module.js:35663)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1640)
```

The project structure is the following:

```
ClientApp
    |_____src 
    |      |____component
    |              |______ev
    |                      |___factory
    |                             |____js
    |                                   |__application.js                                       
    |____assets
    |       |___Models
    |              |____buildingCorridorOpen.mtl
    |              |____buildingCorridorOpen.obj
```

I tried to import the loaders as the following, but the result is the same:

```js
import {MTLLoader} from "three-obj-mtl-loader";
import {OBJLoader} from "three-obj-mtl-loader";
```

I also have tried the .setpath() and then the load(), but the result was the same, same error, i am using the npm version: 6.12.1, and node version: 12.13.1.

The only issue related to this question is the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118013/three-js-do-not-recognise-objloader) stack overflow question.

The javascript is rendering well, except for that, all other meshes  (simple ones, CubeGeometry p.e.) appear in the correct position, except for this one.

Any help, would be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm trying to patch `OBJLoader` to make it more robust. I'll keep you up-to-date ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from `R111`, `THREE.OBJLoader` is now able to parse `OBJ` files containing the `usemap` rendering identifier. However, the identifier will just be ignored since textures are usually defined in the MTL file. Notice that `usemap` is the old-style Wavefront texture reference method.

Your mentioned assets should now load correctly.

Related PR: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/18000